# PackageBaseClass::AnotherClass->Method() - possible in PHP5?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to call methods like this:

```
PackageName::BankAccounts->create('arg1', 'arg2');
```

But I get parse error:

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in ...*

in PHP 5.6.14., but I really feel like I've already seen that style used somewhere.

Am I wrong, or is there a trick to accomplish calling methods in such fashion in PHP5?

Comment: `->` comes after an object, not a class name.

Comment: If you're calling a static method, it's `PackageName::BankAccounts::create()`.

Comment: @Barmar BankAccounts *is* is an object too. PackageName and BankAccounts both are, while create() is a method.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware of `PackageName::BankAccounts::create()` possibility, but my employee wants it done the way I stated in the question.

Comment: If `BankAccounts` is a variable containing an object, you need a `$` before it: `PackageName::$BankAccounts`.

Comment: @Barmar I actually just tried `PackageName::BankAccounts::create()`, and I got a nice little *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)*. That's awkward.

Comment: @Barmar BankAccounts is not a variable, it's a class name.

Comment: Could you show all the class definitions?

Comment: Sure. This is the package: https://github.com/NinoSkopac/promisepay-php/tree/53c30324413ffc4b01ecac3265457433fbedf566. This is the code I'm trying: https://gist.github.com/NinoSkopac/812de2c35a65ce868f0b. But the thing is, the error is a parsing one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94454/discussion-between-nino-skopac-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There we go:

```
<?php

class BankAccount {
    public static function getBankAccountById($id) {
        return array('data', 'more data', '_self' => $id);
    }
}

class BaseClass {
    public static function __callStatic($className, $argsWeWontUse) {
        return new $className;
    }
}

$call = BaseClass::BankAccount()->getBankAccountById('abcdefghijkl123456');

print_r($call);

/*

Array
(
    [0] => data
    [1] => more data
    [_self] => abcdefghijkl123456
)

*/

?>
```

Nevertheless, I appreciate your time Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
(new PromisePay::BankAccountRepository())->getBankAccountById('asdasdasd');
```

To get an object from a class name, you have to use `new` to create the object.

But doing this immediately on a new object doesn't make much sense. You have to add a bank account to the repository before you can retrieve it.

Comment: Alright, I'm thankful for the reply, and will accept it in the next few hours if it remains the best answer. So, about PackageName::Class:Method() pattern, would you say that your answer is the best alternative to that too?

Comment: `PackageName::Class::Method()` is for static methods. `getBankAccountById` is a method that operates on an object.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `getBankAccountById` is a static method, and `PackageName::Class::Method()` yields in a PHP parse error, making it look like the aforementioned invocation format is not permitted in PHP.

Comment: Not according to the examples in the documentation. It shows: `$bankAccount = $repo->getBankAccountById('Account_id');`

Comment: That's the documentation from the original package(mine is a fork). You can see the up to date version of `getBankAccountById` here: https://github.com/NinoSkopac/promisepay-php/blob/59aebc838001cec55f280fc83e9ac1ce0d51e2f9/lib/BankAccountRepository.php

Comment: I linked you the code: the whole repository on GitHub, and the Gist where you can see my experiment.

Comment: Can you distill this problem into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so you can put all the relevant code in the question?